# power BI cannot find function is() in a R script

Tags: r, powerbi

## Dear all

I am running the following R script in power BI, with the purpose of getting "data2016" and "df" as output data (both are data frames). With sapply() I am sourcing the function inputFreq() which is a home made function to compute the frequency of an entry in a vector. The function uses is() inside (among other things, see detail below)

```
setwd("C:/Users/Home/Documents/folder")
data2016 <- read.csv("rawData2016.csv", header = TRUE)
sapply(list.files(pattern="[.]r$", full.names=TRUE), FUN=source)
df <- head(as.data.frame(inputFreq(data2016$var1[1:100])))
```

Message Error

After doing Get Data > Other > r script and pasting (all in power BI enviroment), I get the following error

> Details: "ADO.NET: R script error.
>   Error in inputFreq(data2016$var1[1:100]) : 
>     could not find function "is"
>   Calls: head -> as.data.frame -> inputFreq
>   Execution halted

The function called, inputFreq() has the is() function inside. For info, here´s the function:

```
inputFreq <- function(x){

  if( is(x, "factor") == TRUE ) {
    x <- as.character(x)
  } else {
    x
  }

  a <- sort(x)
  n <- length(a)
  k <- numeric(n)
  f <- numeric(n)

  # vector k: algoritmo para computar la frecuencia maxima en vector 'a'

  k[1] <- 1
  for (i in 2:n){
    if ( a[i]==a[i-1] ){
      k[i] <- 1 + k[i-1]
    }  else {
      k[i] <- 1
    }

  }

  # vector N: algoritmo para imputar la frecuencia maxima de cada a(i)

  f[n] <- k[n]
  for (j in (n-1):1){
    if ( k[j] < k[j+1] ){
      f[j] <- f[j+1]
    }  else {
      f[j] <- k[j]
    }
  }

  return( cbind( "x" = x, "fr.x" = f[match(x,sort(x))] ) )
}
```

## More info

The function has already performed well in the rstudio environment, the problems seems to be when power BI tries to read the is() function from methods-R.

## Any suggestion? many thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried the function `is.factor()` ?

Comment: `is` is in the methods package. Perhaps Power BI does not load it? You could specify the namespace with `methods::is`

Comment: or `library(methods)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that PowerBI uses Rscript.exe, the commandline version of R used to run scripts without a GUI-based front end. [Rscript doesn't load the methods package](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html), which is where the `is` function is defined.

To fix this, do one of the following:

- Add a line `library(methods)` to the top of your script.
- Use `inherits` instead of `is`. [This does almost exactly the same thing](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/class.html), but is defined in the `base` package and hence will always be available.